# mysql naming convention

Tags: php, mysql, naming-conventions, conventions, hungarian-notation

I have generally always used some sort of `Hungarian Notation` for my field names in my tables e.g.

```
#Table Users
u_id, u_name, u_email etc...

#Posts
p_id, p_u_id, p_title, p_content etc...
```

But I have recently been told that this isn't best practice. Is there a more standard way of doing this? I haven't really liked just using the field `id` as this is then requirs you to select `table`.`field` for fields names that appear in mutliple tables when using joins etc.

Your thoughts on what is best practice would be appreciated.

Comment: How is table_field any better than table.field?

Comment: The table can always be aliased to one letter in the query if you like that. Also, after you have more than a handful of tables, you kind of start running out of one-letter acronyms and have to resort to longer and less-guessable acronyms...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best practice is the most comfortable for you or your team. Every programmer has it's own opinion about using notations.

Answer (score 3):

This seems like one of those questions where you'll get numerous answers, all of which are "right." Different teams and environments will prefer different conventions. I even find that my own practice will vary from project to project a little. The only suggestions I could offer are

1. be consistent within projects,
2. don't be overly-verbose,
3. and don't use reserved words

Just my two cents. Wiki'd.

Comment: 3rd is a little undefined. no one can guarantee that specific column name will not become "reserved word" in the future. so using ` is preferred instead of following #3 and praying ;-)

Comment: @zerkms I was referring to the obvious words. But you're right, wrap your field names in back-ticks to be uber-safe.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your working style. There are no fixed set of rules.

I use camelcase tableNameFieldName for e.g catID, catName, catDesc

Answer (score 0):

I personally use lowercase for table names and pluralize. Tables such as 'people' with person records. But I got that from Rails and adopted it after time. Love it though, and this made my databases a whole lot readable. Also using so many underscores will make your databases less readable. Also I divide my database names using _ for development, test, production, alpha, beta, prototype. Once you worked with 100,000 tables or so, you'll stop writing names with too many underscores :)