# naming convention for sql tables

Tags: mysql, sql, code-conversion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mysql naming convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625973/mysql-naming-convention)

What is the best naming convention for sql tables?

Can we name them in both upper and lower case or camel case?

Which is correct?

Comment: It's purely a matter of preference and conforming to any local conventions in place where you work.

Comment: The choice of words that you use for naming your tables is a lot more important than the case of the letters. One widespread convention is to use singular noun forms for your table names (`employee`, `address`, `destination` instead of `employees`, `addresses`, `destinations`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, it doesn't matter too much as long as it's the same format for the entire database. Some prefix with 't_', 'tbl' or don't prefix at all